# why does "str (print ("hello")+"one")" printed "hello noneone" in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I expected it would print "helloone" as when I wrote "str (print ())+"one"" the output was "Noneone" because "print()" is None .so if I am putting "str (print ("hello"))+"one"" then it will add "hello" and "one" and should print "helloone" but it gave the output "hello noneone".

Comment: are you sure `print ("hello")+"one"` will print `hello noneone`?

Comment: No sorry it's,[str (print ("hello "))+"one"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are printing "hello" like this

```
    print("hello")
```

it is printing the text **hello** and the command is completed. so it returns a NoneType value which is **None**. Then this value is being converted to string and becomes 'None' and then it is added to 'one' which gives you 'Noneone'

Answer (score 0):

It gives this Output because it prints hello, then print returns None which is then shown again (in the REPL). Print doesn't return what it has printed but rather `None`